# What do Islam say about competition in non-religious worldly matters?

Tags: sharia

> What do Islam say about competition in non-religious worldly matters?

To clarify, this has nothing to do with this question: [Are competitions haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2939/are-competitions-haram)

Basically, I'm asking, if two people compete between each other in non-religious worldly matter (and not afterlife), for instance if I compete my classmate and I about scores or marks in a subject (that can be islamic education) is it haram? Or if two people compete about who's gonna persuade the other, is it haram? Because this can result in non-islamic acts such as insults, aggression... And **will** cause one of them to loose along with it's implications. *En plus*, those are just worldly matters.

Comment: No, It is not haram but when you realize that if you continue to discussion it will harm him just end it.

Comment: Insults and aggression can be exhibited in a number of circumstances outside of a competitive environment. So just because they should be avoided doesn't mean competition should be avoided.

The prophet sallallohu alaihi wassallam was a very honest and successful businessman having learnt the trade from his uncle Abu Talib, and we all know business is a very competitive environment.

Comment: In spite of what you say, I don't see how this isn't a duplicate of that question. Surely, if organized contests/competitions are allowed, then informally competing with a friend would be as well. I think it's clear that the other question was asking about the same thing as you, in addition to other things, while not being too broad: "I want to know the permissibility of such contests. ... What about these two? (contests of luck and contests of skill)."

Answer (score 1):

I don't get what do you mean by "non-religious worldly matters". Because, whatever you do in this world will be questioned at the day of reckoning. Religion is a life style and you can't separate it from daily life.

If you are asking stuff which are other then "praying", my answer is;

If your aim to this competition is doing good things (getting higher score from exam, doing your job better way) it's  okay to compete, but if your aim is insulting and abusing your competitors, it's not okay to compete.

It's like internet , or other daily life stuffs. What you do and what you aim is decider to if it's okay to do it.

You can read more in [here](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=articles&id=160708) with more Ayath and Hadith examples