# Is participating in surveys with rewards halal?

Tags: halal-haram, gambling, internet

Sometime back I got a message from Google which is below
"You have personally selected to participate in our 2015 Annual Visitor Survey! Finish our quick 30-second survey, and to say "Thank You", we will give you a prize worth Rs 50,000!"

My question is if I do survey and I won will it Halal for me?

Comment: First of all, this is most likely a scam. As far as I know, google offers so such thing. If you google "Annual Visitor Survey Google" you get a bunch listings on the scam, viruses and malware. If I were you, I wouldn't attempt this. Do you really think Google will give you 50,000 Rs for 30 seconds? No. 

As far as the concept being halal. Sure it is. Why wouldn't it be?

Answer (score 1):

#### It's a scam.

To check if this is has any relation to Google or not, type into Google [`"2015 Annual Visitor Survey"`](https://www.google.com/#q=%222015+Annual+Visitor+Survey%22).  Unsurprisingly, we find that this is a scam.  This particular scam is described in various forms at e.g. [Fake Google Chrome Questionnaire - "2015 Annual Visitor Survey"](https://www.onlinethreatalerts.com/article/2015/4/22/fake-google-chrome-questionnaire-2015-annual-visitor-survey/) and [Malware Tips](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-2015-annual-visitor-survey/) describes how to remove this:

> If you are seeing random pop-up ads from 2015 Annual Visitor Survey within Internet Explorer, Firefox and Google Chrome, then your computer is infected with an adware or a potentially unwanted program.

#### Participating in surveys with rewards.

(This part of the question is a partial duplicate of [Are competitions haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2939/17163).)

Since it's a scam, we can't be sure about the tricks the scammers might use; they might deceive you into doing something haram.  However, suppose it weren't a scam (it is, but just hypothetically).

The only problem would be if it were a form of gambling, but this doesn't apply since there's no entry fee.  [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/14220) said this would be permissible.